# PHP SDK: Post to FB application's wall as the app itself

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

There are a lot of questions on SO about this, but not exactly what I am looking for.

In my case, users can log in through Facebook/Twitter/other. And they can upload an image.
Once they upload an image, two things will happen. The FB user's status is updated with an attachment to the link. And on the FB App's wall, a status update is also posted but by the application itself and not by the user. I am having trouble with this last part. So the user does not have to be logged in through Facebook for this latter to occur.

My code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$attachment = array(
'message' => 'A user just posted a new item',
'name' => $tag,
'caption' => $desc,
'link' =>  WEBURL,
'description' => '',
'picture' => $img,
'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Go to item',
                  'link' => WEBURL))
);


$facebook->api('/'.PAGEID.'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```

Answer (score 0):

An application's wall behaves exactly like a page's wall or a user's wall. Lookup the documentation for those.

Comment: I know it does, and I have looked up the documentation. The only thing that I am missing is how one can post as the app's owner to the app's wall.